# Do the user-interaction and user-behavior tags add anything useful to the site?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm puzzled here, two of our biggest tags, with lots of followers, are [user-behavior](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-behavior) and [user-interaction](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interaction). They're pretty close to being intrinsic tags (applicable to the whole scope of the site). But since they're highly followed and frequently used I'm not sure about removing them.

What value do these tags provide and how should they be used? Should we keep them?

Think of it this way; tags should be able to stand on their own as the only  tag on a question; that's one of the criteria for a meta tag; meta tags don't work on their own because they really don't meaningfully describe the problem space. Does a question tagged only "user behavior" really make sense? Or "user interaction"? Is there ever a question in either of these tags that wouldn't be better served with more specific tags like [scrolling](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrolling) or [click](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/click)?

Answer (score 3):

We should blacklist the [user-interaction](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interaction) and [user-behavior](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-behavior) tags, silently removing them from all questions and preventing their use in the future.

Comment: I'm not strictly advocating this action, just saying it's on the table, so vote if you want this to happen/not happen.

Answer (score 0):

We need to keep them if there is no way to make a tag 'banned'. Users will always try to add it, so we can't just remove the tag... we have to programattically indicate that it is redundant or the UX of a new user will be confusing, and the mods will be doing silly removals on half the tickets.

If tags can't be banned, we could at least make them synonyms with a 'ux' tag, that has a description saying it's redundant.

Comment: We CAN blacklist the tags, which means they'd be deleted and permanently removed, we'd just have to get someone from SE to do it. In fact the 'UX'/'UI' tags are already blacklisted for that reason

Answer (score 0):

I can see your point. They are kind of strange labelled. Improvements to the tags can be made. I’d be more than happy if they were synonyms to [interaction](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interaction) and [behaviour](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behaviour). In that context I agree, disregard the *user-* prefix and it’ll be fine.

User Experience is much more than just interaction and behaviour. A lot of the questions is design related, which with the suggestion above would mean that the popular tag [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) would meet the same destiny. To me the suggestion is wrong.

My suggestion is to create tag synonyms of *user-interaction* and *user-behaviour* to [interaction](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interaction) and [behvaiour](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behvaiour) respectively instead.

Comment: I think [interaction design] works well, but it's not quite the same as "user interaction". As is the behavior tag doesn't appear to be well applied either...

Comment: @BenBrocka I agree. Keep the [interaction-design] 'cause it's different. But change [user-interaction] to [interaction] AND [user-bahviour] to [behaviour]. If that's not possible, I think it's better to keep the existing tags rather than silently delete them.

Comment: I'm just not sure how "behavior" itself is a useful tag. If it involves a user, doesn't it by definition include some interaction of some sort? If there is an interaction, isn't behavior inherent? Unless it's used in a narrow, defined scope like behavioral learning (conditioning) I can't see the use of behavior as a tag at all.

Comment: @BenBrocka Now we're getting somewhere. Great points of defining interaction a part of behaviour. In my world *interaction* is the activity but the behaviour is more of an attitude symptom which leads to an interaction with an intent or bias. We're definately getting very close to COGSCI.SE instead of UX.SE - but I think it's not a problem. Disciplines tend to overlap each other...

Comment: "behavior" is still a uselessly general tag on Cogsci. I'm not saying it's off topic, it's just...not useful. I'm puzzled as to what people think of when they "follow" it

Comment: @BenBrocka LOL! "I think I just learnd a bit of Cognitive Science in my System Developer masters program. I need to follow a tag that gets me fast up to speed. Wait, what's this? Yeah - I just found the *user-behaviour* tag! I'd better follow it!"